# Why a scheme on $A$ satisfies this?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let be $n$ a positive integer and $A:=\{1,2,...,2n\}$. Suppose that $\phi \colon A\to A$ is a bijection such that $\phi (i)\neq i$ and $\phi (\phi (i))=i$ for each $i\in A$, and there is no $i,j\in A$ such that $i<j<\phi (i)<\phi (j)$. Such a bijection is called a scheme on $A$.

Now, we suppose that there exists $i<2n$ with $i<\phi(i)$ and let $j$ be the maximal integer such that $i\le j<\phi (i)$ and $\phi(j)<\phi(i)$.

**Lemma:** $\phi (j)=j+1$

**Proof:** Indeed, asume that $\phi(j)\neq j+1$. Then, clearly $j+1<\phi(j)$, and it follows from the definition of a scheme that $j+1<\phi(j+1)<\phi(j)$, wich contradicts the choice of $j$.

My question is, why is $j+1<\phi(j)$? I tried to suppose that $\phi(j)<j+1$ to find a contradiction, but I failed.

Any hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Introduction

I'd like to offer my take on the problem.  Unfortunately, I have no idea how to use the cool typesetting features of this site, so you'll have to content yourselves with just a little $\TeX$ here and there.

As other posters have pointed out, the Lemma as stated is incorrect.  This is usually a symptom of a mathematical statement where symbols fly fast and furious. So, let's try a different, more structured approach.

### Defining a scheme

A **scheme** is a pairing of a ordered set with some structure on it, provided by a certain kind of bijection.  In more detail:  Begin with a finite, linearly ordered set $S$ (for example, some subset of the integers), and consider a bijection $f$ on $S$.

First, we postulate that $f$ pairs the elements of $S$ (in what follows, $x$, $y$, and $k$ are of type "element of $S$"):

(0) $\quad f(x) \neq x \quad$ for all $x$

(1) $\quad f(f(x)) = x \quad$ for all $x \quad.$

(In the lingo, $f$ is known as an **involution**.)

Notice that these properties of $f$ do not involve the linear order on $S$.  Our next property relates $f$ to this order.  For all $x,y$:

(2) $\quad x < y < f(x) \implies x < f(y) < f(x)$.

Of course, since $f$ is an involution, we could just as easily have written:

(2) $\quad x < y < f(x) \iff x < f(y) < f(x)$.

All the above, taken together, define a scheme.  Notice that property (2) ensures that for any $x$ with $x < f(x)$, we have that $f$ defines a scheme on the subinterval $[x,f(x)]$ of $S$.

(The proof is a walkover:  Properties (0), (1), and (2) hold for all elements of $S$, and $f$ satisfies the bijection property for all elements of $S$, so we only need to check that $f$ is closed on $[x,f(x)]$, which is exactly what property (2) says.)

### Reinterpreting the lemma

Any reader armed with a scrap of paper and a pen should already have a basic understanding of what a scheme "is".  Now let us return to the original poster's statement and try to understand and correct it.

Before we proceed, I'd like to introduce one more bit of terminology.  We have seen that $f$ pairs elements of $S$.  Because $S$ is ordered, $f$ pairs a "lower" element with a "higher" one.  Let us call the lower element a **valley**, and the higher element its corresponding **peak**.

The OP first asks us to consider some $k$ for which $k < f(k)$.  (In our new terminology, $k$ is a valley.)  The rest of the statement is restricted to the interval $[k,f(k)]$, which we know remains a scheme under $f$.  So far so good.

The OP's lemma was supposed to have us conclude $f(x) = x+1$ for some "maximal" $x$. How can we reinterpret this in our more general statement, where $+$ is not even necessarily defined?  Simple: we are looking for some valley $x$, such that there is no $y$ between $x$ and the corresponding peak $f(x)$, ie no $y$ satisfying $x < y < f(x)$.

To conclude that there are no elements between $x$ and $f(x)$, it suffices to show either that there are no valleys, or that there are no peaks.  This is because property (2) tells us that on subintervals of $S$, valleys and peaks come in pairs.

To rule out valleys, we could let $x$ be the maximal valley on $[k,f(k)]$.  This is, I believe, the OP's intended lemma.  The OP forgot to stipulate that $x$ should be a valley.

But notice that we could just as easily let $f(x)$ be the minimal peak on $[k,f(k)]$.  This will also guarantee that there are no elements between $x$ and $f(x)$.

### Some other little facts about schemes

The OP included as part of the definition of a scheme that the set should have an even number of elements.  However, we can prove this: properties (0) and (1) imply that the elements of $S$ are paired, and hence $S$ has an even number of elements.

Also, since any subinterval $[x,f(x)]$ (where $x$ is a valley, of course) is a scheme, we can conclude that each such subinterval also has an even number of elements.

Comment: I thank you for writing this introduction, but I don't see any problem with the original statement that I wrote.  Hagen's answer is not correct; he thought he proved that $\phi(j)<j$, but he didn't.

Comment: Your original statement is not correct for the reason I mentioned.

Take $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$, let $\phi(1) = 4$, $\phi(2) = 3$, $\phi(3) = 2$, and $\phi(4) = 1$.  Let $i = 1$, let $j = 3$.

Comment: In fact, from your problem statement it should be clear that $j$ always equals $\phi(i) - 1$.

Comment: Aahh, sorry, now I see it. Thank you, I'll read what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

With $j'=\phi(j)$ we see that $j'<\phi(i)$ and $i\le\phi(j')=j<\phi(i)$. By maximiality of $j$, we conclude $j'<j$. Hence the lemma is either wrong or no schemes exist or $\phi(i)>i$ always implies $\phi(i)=i+1$.

---

As it turns out, any valid sequence of parentheses gives rise to a scheme, by mapping each $i$ to the position of the corresponding closing/opening parentesis for the opening/closing parenthesis at position $i$. Therefore, the lemma is in fact wrong.

Comment: You have that $i\le \phi (j')=j<\phi (i)$, not that $i\le j'<\phi (i)$.